# View Source on my websites always looks nasty, why isn't the HTML lining up properly?

Tags: html, format

I do a decent job of formatting my HTML and keeping it clean, but every time I view source there are elements all over the place. I guess that's fine since it won't make the page load any faster or slower and makes it harder to copy, but it just looks ugly and I wish it didnt

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Source in a web browser will show exactly what the server sent to the client.  If you're really formatting your HTML nicely and it doesn't look exactly the same on the client, then there's something else in the middle that's making it not line up the same, such as a server-side technology like PHP or ASP.NET which is being used to generate some of the markup.

Also it's possible you're seeing it different due to spaces.  If in your development environment you're mixing spaces and tabs and have one tab equal to 4 spaces, for example, and then in the browser it might be one tab equal to 8 spaces, then things won't line up right.  To fix this, either always use tabs or always use spaces.  Most decent IDEs will swap between tabs and spaces automatically for you (like Visual Studio).

Some browser tools like Firebug and Chrome's Developer Tools will show the DOM tree as the browser understands it.  This is a translation of the DOM back to HTML and is not likely to be the exact same as what the server sent the content.  It is formatted perfectly though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your HTML is not lined up properly in your browser's View Source. It would be helpful to actually see your HTML.

Some of the common culprits include:

- a mixture of tabs and manual spaces for indenting code (if you want things to look pretty, do one or the other).
- possibly a mixture of Windows, Unix, and Macintosh line breaks (CR/LF), which can happen if code is edited from multiple computers. I've had issues with this, but I'm not sure if it would cause the issues you're describing; perhaps not. (I'm sure others can comment more knowledgeably on that possibility.)
- your site is managed through a CMS that emits terrible HTML

It may be useful for you to look at [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). I haven't used it yet, but I've always heard good things.